# Composer installation with curl not working in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Below is the Dockerfile I  have for creating a docker image. It  was working so great but today I tried to build image in `--no-cache` mode since than I am having the issue. The error message detail is given bellow.

I repeat, it was working fine but now runs into error. Tried searching few solutions but nothing worked.

**In particular this command is not working** `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

```
FROM alpine:edge

MAINTAINER SamratShakya <samrat.shakya@nepallink.net>

# Install packages
RUN apk --update add \
        curl \
        php7 \
        php7-dom \
        php7-fpm \
        php7-mbstring \
        php7-mcrypt \
        php7-opcache \
        php7-pdo \
        php7-pdo_mysql \
        php7-pdo_pgsql \
        php7-mysqli \
        php7-xml \
        php7-simplexml \
        php7-common \
        php-simplexml \
        php7-phar \
        php7-openssl \
        php7-json \
        php7-ctype \
        php7-session \
        php7-tokenizer \
        php7-xmlwriter \
        nodejs \
        git \
        ca-certificates \
        nginx \
        wget \
        libcurl \
        php7-curl \
        supervisor \

        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*


RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
  --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

This is the error message I get in  jenkins logs.

**Error message:**

```
Step 4/21 : RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php   --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer

 ---> Running in f79b6610ae38

[91mError relocating /usr/bin/php: explicit_bzero: symbol not found
[0m[91mcurl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16133)

[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php   --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer' returned a non-zero code: 127
PROBLEM IN IMAGE BUILD !!
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: the command you say it's not working does not match the one in your Dockerfile

Comment: i have just removed the few parameters and adding them does not matter too.

Comment: so please update the error message and the Dockerfile with the correct command (without removing the `--`)

Answer (score 0):

Try again with:

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
  php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me so as a workaround, What I did is added the composer as multistage image. I added composer separately and copied it to my alpine image as bellow.

```
FROM composer:1.5.1 AS composer

FROM alpine:edge 
#copying composer from another image and making it work
COPY --from=php-composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN  ln -s /usr/bin/php7 /usr/bin/php
```

Regarding the issue I had. I am not able to extract the exact cause